# Is $\mathbb{Z}^0$ the empty set or the set containing a point $(0)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is probably a really stupid question, but I couldn't find any answer for it on the internet.

Is $\mathbb{Z}^0$ the empty set or the set containing a point $(0)$?

Comment: I think it is $\{ 0\}$, because it is a subspace, hence has to contain zero.

Comment: How many functions are there from the empty set to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: For a question like this, you should go to your definition.  What do you mean by $\Bbb Z^0$?  It can be, as Reveilark's answer says, the functions from $0$ to $\Bbb Z$, and his/her answer is correct for that definition.  It could be the set of length $0$ sequences from $\Bbb Z$, which has the same result.  If you define $\Bbb Z^n$ as the $n$-fold Cartesian product, you have to define the empty Cartesian product as the empty set. I haven't seen that as standard, I have only seen empty products of numbers defined as $1$.

Comment: I was defining it as the n-fold Cartesian product; I should have made it more clear. I haven't had a formal set theory course yet.

Comment: @umop aplsdn: Then the answer below still holds, that is, $\mathbb Z^0 = \{\emptyset\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A^B$ is the collection of functions $B\to A$, and $0$ denotes the emptyset, then there is only one function from $0$ to any set: the empty function, whose graph is empty (in categorical terms, $0$ is initial in $\mathbf{Set}$).

As such, $A^0$ contains a single point, for any set $A$.